# Is there a way to access CompanyName from the LMA?

Tags: lma

Is there a way to access CompanyName from the LMA?

I notice that there is no field in the LMA that specifies the Company Name as listed in the subscriber org's "Company Info".  The only way I know to find this name is to search for it under Subscribers, as this is data not available in the PBO instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom Formula field on sfLma__License__c and called it Company__c.
The value for the formula field is sfLma__Lead__r.Company